# CodeIgniter form validation not working on submission

Tags: php, codeigniter, validation

I'm working on learning CodeIgniter and have run into a bit of hiccup.
I have my login page (very basic) showing up. However, when I click the submit button to run the form_validation, the page refreshes and then gives an ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error.

The URL for the main login looks like localhost/xxxx/xxxx/index.php/main .
When I submit the form, it changes to localhost/xxxx/xxxx/main/login_validation

I've loaded 'database' and 'sessions' into my autoload library, as well as 'form' and 'url' into the autoload helper.

I've also gone into the .htaccess and used the rewrite mod to change the RewriteBase to /xxxx/xxxx/

I'm not sure if I need to change something else in my config or route file...any help would be much appreciated!

**main.php**

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Main extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        $this->login();
    }

    public function Login(){

        $this->load->view('login');
    }

    public function Members(){
        $this->load->view('members');
    }

    public function Login_validation(){

        $this->load->library('form_validation');

        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'required|trim|xss_clean');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required|md5|trim');

        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            redirect('main/members');

        } else{
            $this->load->view('login');
        }

    }
}
```

**login.php**

```
    <h1>Login</h1>

    <?php

    echo form_open('main/login_validation');

    echo validation_errors();

    echo "<p>Email ";
    echo form_input('email');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>Password ";
    echo form_password('password');
    echo "</p>";

    echo "<p>";
    echo form_submit('login_submit', 'Login');
    echo "</p>";

    echo form_close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Make file name `Main.php` not `main.php`

Comment: @wolfgang1983 thank you for the suggestion. I updated the file name and reloaded the MAMP server, but it is still giving me the same error.

Comment: do you have the url helper loaded? ifso use `echo form_open(base_url('main/login_validation');`

Answer (score 0):

Try change main.php to Main.php to avoid controller not found on unix server but not sure its the reason for ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED. This could be compression issue.  Try disable compression first if its enabled

```
 $config['compress_output'] = FALSE ;
```

If you echo something before the final output while compression is enabled, you could get ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED.
Also if you are redirecting in Login_validation() ,
Comment out redirection and check if any error occur when form was submitted.
If I may ask why naming your methods like

```
Login_validation()
```

Instead

```
login_validation()
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. The compress_output had already been set to FALSE. The Login_validation() was a mistake on my part, as I was trying to see if it would make any difference when trying to fix it prior to asking. I just forgot to switch it back.

I updated the file name to Main.php and restarted the MAMP server, but no luck

Answer (score 0):

Ok change

```
echo form_open('main/login_validation');
```

To

```
echo form_open( site_url('main/login_validation'));
```

Comment: Still gives me the same issue...I cleared my cache and restarted the server, but still nothing. I opened it up using Firefox just to make sure it wasn't Chrome-specific, but it gives me a similar error saying it can't establish a connection to the server.